# How to connect existing Google Group to Google Cloud Admin Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an existing Google Group (I am an owner) and I want to automatically add newly registered users on the website to the Google Group.
The API to do this is straightforward, and it requires an auth key from a Google Cloud admin account. I have an admin account under the same email as the Google Group, but I cannot figure out how to connect the Group to the account.

Comment: Modify the project IAM binding and add the group as an identity.

Comment: Note: you are using the term/phrase **Google Cloud Admin account**. There is no such account in Google Cloud.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I used the wrong terminology. I was able to add the group in Role Access Approval Approver.